# qml Canvas loadImage("image://imageName") cannot load "image://imageName", when loadImage second used

Tags: qt, canvas, qml, qt-quick

The signal is `setMiddlePrecisionBitmap` ,the slot is:

```
Connections{
    target: config_S2;

    onSetMiddlePrecisionBitmap:{

        console.log("setMiddlePrecisionBitmap()");           
        background.poster = "image://PretreatmentImage/lowImage";
        background.loadImage(background.poster);
        background.imageData = background.getContext("2d").createImageData(background.poster);          
        background.context.drawImage(background.poster,0,0,width,height);
        background.requestPaint();
    }
}
```

When the signal is emitted, the Image `"image://PretreatmentImage/lowImage"` is loaded by a `Canvas` (`background`). But when the signal is emitted a second time, the `"image://PretreatmentImage/lowImage"` is changed but the image loaded in the `Canvas` (`background`) is not changed. Why?

I guess the when loadImage() the Image is buffered in canvas(background), so when calling `loadImage()` the second time, the image name is not changed, so canvas(background) does not change.

How to solve this?

Comment: @derM calling a `markDirty` does not suffice in this scenario? [It's been a while since the last time I've used `Canvas`]

Comment: Oops. Might be working. Haven't used `Canvas` a lot. Just at my very beginning, for some tests. I don't have the possibilities to test it. I delete my comment until I can confirm the right solution. Thanks for your remark, BaCaRoZzo